# Can AIR applicaiton request elevation to admin privileges on Windows 7

Tags: windows, air, uac

Can AIR applicaiton request elevation to admin privileges at startup?
I need access database installed along with the applicaiton and having issues with it.
It works only when I manually start it with "Run as administration" via menu.